# React + Web3, making call from componentDidMount but web3 not ready?

Tags: web3js, react

I'm trying to load some data from a smart contract from within `componentDidMount`. Calling the contract from within here didn't seem to work as web3 provider wasn't ready, so I added an event listener for 'load' and did it in there.

However, it seems like my web3 object still is not yet ready to be called.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {

      if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {

        MyContract.methods.getValue().call(function(error, result){
          if (error) { console.log(error); }
          if (result) {
            console.log(result);
          }
        });
      }
}
```

I get this error upon making the contract call:

```
Error: Provider not set or invalid
```

I can confirm that logging `web3.currentProvider.isMetaMask` returns `true` right before this contract call. A bit confusing, any ideas?

** Upon further investigation, it appears that `MyContract.currentProvider` is not yet set at this point. So its not the web3 injection from MetaMask.

Answer (score 2):

It's not ready so that means its asynchronous, so in your `componentDidMount()` you need something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const value = await contractName.methods.getValue().call();
}
```

Now, when you use the `await` syntax that means you do have to mark the `componentDidMount()` as being `async` like so:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const value = await contractName.methods.getValue().call();
}
```

Also, you mentioned you are loading data, so you should have a class-based component where you are initializing data from like so:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { manager: '' };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont quite sure but it's not bad to test this :

```
async componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      let result ;
      if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        result = await MyContract.methods.getValue().call();
      }
}
```